# Vagrant configure eth0

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, vagrant

I started using Vagrant recently to quickly install virtual machines.
I noticed that my network configuration isn't perfect, but I can't get it right.

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'libvirt'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root", disabled: true
  config.vm.provider "libvirt" do |lv|
        lv.driver = "kvm"
  end #config.vm.provider
  #how many hosts to deploy?
  n = 1
  (10..n+9).each do |i|
        config.vm.define "#{i}" do |vs|
                vs.vm.hostname = "vs-#{i}"
                vs.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.#{i}"
        end #config.vm.define
  end #loop

  #copy local ssh key to vm with ansible
  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "vagrant-provision.yml"
        ## Debugging
        #ansible.verbose =  true
        #ansible.verbose="vvvvv"
  end

end #Vagrant.configure
```

My box starts up correctly and it is also reachable via the defined IP address (10.0.0.X), but this address is on eth1. Vagrant is creating another interface first, eth0, and this interface receives a 192.168.121.XXX address. I would like to get rid of this one, but I don't know how.

This is the output of *vagrant ssh-config*:

```
$ vagrant ssh-config 
Host 10
  HostName 192.168.121.148
  User vagrant
  Port 22
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/max/vagrant/vs/.vagrant/machines/10/libvirt/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

This is from within the vm:

```
root@vs-10:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:b1:1f:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.121.148/24 brd 192.168.121.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 3503sec preferred_lft 3503sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feb1:1ffd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c8:05:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.10/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@vs-10:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
      address 10.0.0.10
      netmask 255.255.255.0
#VAGRANT-END
```

As you see, the defined address in my Vagrantfile is getting inserted in the interfaces file, but for eth1. eth0 is not defined there, but still shows up when I run *ip addr*. I would like to have the address 10.0.0.10 on the interface eth0 and get rid of the 192.168.121.XXX address.